# ggplot2 plot points when y value in NA

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe where the x value (discrete) is present and want to include on the x-axis in the plot; however, its y value is NA

I still want to show the x value even though y is NA. Is there a way to do this in ggplot2?

Currently, it simply skips the first two rows that has the NA value.

```
  ggplot(tChartDF()[['df']], aes(
    x = factor(tChartDF()[['df']][['Rare event date']], levels = unique(tChartDF()[['df']][['Rare event date']])),
    y = unlist(tChartDF()[['df']][['days_between']]),
  )) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = unlist(tChartDF()[['timeScaleCL']]), color = input$tChartCLColour, lwd = input$tChartCLWidth) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = unlist(tChartDF()[['timeScaleUL']]), linetype = 'dashed', lwd = 1, color = 'red') +
    geom_hline(yintercept = unlist(tChartDF()[['timeScaleLL']]), linetype = 'dashed', lwd = 1, color = 'red') +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    theme_classic() +
    geom_line(aes(group = 1), lwd = input$tChartLineWidth, color= input$tChartLineColour) +
    geom_point(size = input$tChartMarkerSize, color = input$tChartMarkerColour) +
    labs(title = input$tChartPlotTitle, x = input$tChartPlotXLabel, y = input$tChartPlotYLabel) +
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(size = 24, face = 'bold', family = 'Arial', hjust = 0.5),
      plot.margin = margin(0, 1, 0, 0, "cm"),
      axis.title = element_text(size = 20, face = 'bold', family = 'Arial'),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 16, face = 'bold', family = 'Arial'),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = as.numeric(input$tChartXOrientation), vjust = 0.5),
      axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, 'cm'),
    ) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

As seen, it only starts plotting at date: 2022/12/15 (ignoring the previous values in the table) columns `y` and `mr` have the `NA` values.

For the plot, I only care about the first two columns (Rare events and days_between). I tried selecting only those two columns and plotting but it still ignores the first two rows.

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: One option would be to set the y values to 0 if they're NA.

Comment: Please do not post an image of data [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). If you want to post your data type e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` (for the first ten rows of data) into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....`  into your post.

Answer (score 0):

If we start with something like

```r
mt <- mtcars
mt$mpg[c(3,6,9)] <- NA
```

and plot the line as in

```r
ggplot(mt, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot with lines, no null points]

we don't see the missing points (not a surprise). We can add them this way:

```r
transform(mt, mpg2 = ifelse(is.na(mpg), max(mpg, na.rm = TRUE) + 1, mpg)) |>
  ggplot(aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg2), data = ~ subset(., is.na(mpg)), shape = 1)
```

[image: ggplot with null points at the top]

This can easily be adapted to be at the bottom, using different shapes/colors, perhaps even on an explicitly-gray background (top/bottom ribbon).

Comment: Thank you! Please correct me if I misunderstood your solution but I'm looking to include the label on the x-axis but hide the `geom_point` and `geom_line` completely for the first date. Please check the desired result image I appended to the question

Comment: Interesting feedback, SevenSouls. Really, though, _sample data_. I don't have your data, I'm faking it by modifying `mtcars` the way I did. It would be far better (for both of us) if we shared the same data (shape, classes, etc). (Also, it appears you're setting this in shiny based on `tChartDF()`; please just assign data to `x` and simplify what's going on. There are several other non-standard things going on in your code I'd like to suggest changes to, but I can't do it without better context.)